# Running Localstack SQS using Docker Compose; While starting container giving error '/tmp/localstack': Device or resource busy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-sqs, localstack

I'm trying to run sqs with localstack using docker compose to execute application tests but localstack container not starting.

```
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack_main
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
      - "8055:8080"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - "./localstack_data:/tmp/localstack" # Mounts the local directory to the container
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" # Mounts the docker socket
#    tmpfs:
#      - /tmp/localstack:exec,mode=777
```

Getting error in container logs

```
LocalStack supervisor: starting
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 15) starting
ERROR: 'rm -rf "/tmp/localstack"': exit code 1; output: b"rm: cannot remove '/tmp/localstack': Device or resource busy\n"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/runtime/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/runtime/main.py", line 20, in main
    infra.start_infra(asynchronous=False)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/infra.py", line 220, in start_infra
    files.rm_rf(config.dirs.tmp)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/files.py", line 214, in rm_rf
    shutil.rmtree(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 763, in rmtree
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 761, in rmtree
    os.rmdir(path, dir_fd=dir_fd)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/tmp/localstack'
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 15) returned with exit code 1
LocalStack supervisor: exiting
```

How to fix ?

Comment: You are mounting `/tmp/localstack` (volumes) and you're saying to use `/tmp/localstack` as a tmpfs. Attempting to do both at the same time is causing the issue. Pick one

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans removed the tmpfs still the same error trace

Comment: Based on the ['getting started' document](https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/installation/#docker-compose), it indicates that you should use the folder `/var/lib/localstack`, and not `/tmp/localstack`

Comment: Try adding `:rw` at end of your volumes, like `"./localstack_data:/tmp/localstack:rw"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the localstack bootup code, which exists on `/opt/code/localstack/localstack`, which attempts to clear the configured temp folder on startup.

This process will handle a permission error, but when you have mounted a file system, you receive a different error - `Device busy`, which causes the code to not start up, as that exception is not caught by the cleanup code.

What it's implying, though, is that the *temporary* folder is really not a place to put your code/data. It indicates also that the entire folder will be *purged* every run, which sounds like a bad thing?

The ['basic' openstack docker-compose](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) indicates the following:

```
- "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
```

So, it seems that using this pattern - mapping `./localstack_data` to `/var/lib/localstack` is the right thing to do in this case:

```
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack_main
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "4571:4571"
      - "8055:8080"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs
      - DEBUG=1
      - PERSISTENCE=1
    volumes:
      - "./localstack_data:/var/lib/localstack" # Mounts the local directory to the container
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" # Mounts the docker socket
```

Note - I have removed `DATA_DIR`, and added `PERSISTENCE` [based on the localstack documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/filesystem/), which states:

> `DATA_DIR` implicitly points to `/var/lib/localstack/state` if persistence is enabled. Use `PERSISTENCE=1` to enable persistence. If `DATA_DIR` is set, its value is ignored, a warning is logged and `PERSISTENCE` is set to 1.

Comment: The use of /tmp appears to be from pre v1 localstack. There's a ['migration' document here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/6398) which explains what changed.